# How to implement your own merge operator which correctly merges cold observables

Tags: system.reactive

Does anyone know how the merge operator is implemented? I was surprised to find that the Merge operator could merge cold observables correctly:

```
         var odd = new int[] { 1, 3 }.ToObservable().Trace("odd");
         var even = new int[] { 2, 4 }.ToObservable().Trace("even");

         odd.Merge(even).Dump("Merged");
```

Output:

```
odd1: Subscribe()
even1: Subscribe()
odd1: OnNext(1)
Merged on 1 -->1
even1: OnNext(2)
Merged on 1 -->2
odd1: OnNext(3)
Merged on 1 -->3
even1: OnNext(4)
Merged on 1 -->4
odd1: OnCompleted()
odd1: Dispose()
even1: OnCompleted()
even1: Dispose()
Merged on 1   completed
```

I soon released that the ToObservable() call was using the Scheduler.CurrentThread to get its work done, allowing "cooperative scheduling" to occur. I built my own observable implementation for the odd numbers using a recursive call to Scheduler.CurrentThread.Schedule(). This allowed the Merge operator to behave as it did for the  new int[] { 1, 3, 5}.ToObservable() observable. So far so good. I am now trying to figure out how the merge operator works under the hood to allow the cooperative scheduling.  I have written my own version of the merge operator to try to help my understanding. I have tried scheduling the subscribe calls to the observables being merged in two different ways but neither replicate the original merge behaviour.

```
   public class MergedObservable<T> : IObservable<T>
   {
      private readonly IObservable<T> mSource;
      private readonly IObservable<T> mSecond;

      public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
      {
         Scheduler.CurrentThread.Schedule(() =>
        {
           mSource.Subscribe(internalObserver);
           Scheduler.CurrentThread.Schedule(() =>
           {
              mSecond.Subscribe(internalObserver);
           });
        });
      }
   }

odd1: Subscribe()
odd1: OnNext(1)
Merged on 1 -->1
even1: Subscribe()
odd1: OnNext(3)
Merged on 1 -->3
even1: OnNext(2)
Merged on 1 -->2
odd1: OnCompleted()
odd1: Dispose()
even1: OnNext(4)
Merged on 1 -->4
even1: OnCompleted()
Merged on 1   completed
even1: Dispose()
```

or when using scheduleAsync I have:

```
     Scheduler.CurrentThread.ScheduleAsync(async (s, t) =>
     {
        retVal.Add(mSource.Subscribe(internalObserver));
        await s.Yield();
        retVal.Add(mSecond.Subscribe(internalObserver));
        await s.Yield();
        return Disposable.Empty;
     });

odd1: Subscribe()
odd1: OnNext(1)
Merged on 1 -->1
even1: Subscribe()
odd1: OnNext(3)
Merged on 1 -->3
even1: OnNext(2)
Merged on 1 -->2
odd1: OnCompleted()
odd1: Dispose()
even1: OnNext(4)
Merged on 1 -->4
even1: OnCompleted()
Merged on 1   completed
even1: Dispose()
```

In both cases the call to the first subscribe produces calls to OnNext before the call to Subscribe on the next observable. What am I missing? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think writing the question helped me understand the problem a little better. I didn't need to recursively schedule or call yield. I just needed to schedule the two calls to subscribe:

```
      Scheduler.CurrentThread.Schedule(() =>
     {
        mSource.Subscribe(internalObserver);
        mSecond.Subscribe(internalObserver);
     });
```